# Conditionally add pipe using function argument if argument is not null with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function with an argument `subset` that has the default value of `NULL`. Within the function if `subset` is `NULL` I do not want to add a conditional pipe. Otherwise, I want to use the value of `subset` within the pipe:

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(subset = NULL){
  
  iris %>% 
    {if (is.null(substitute(subset))) . else filter(., {{ subset }} < 2.2)}
  
}

f() # gives error posted below
## Desired output: entire iris dataset

f(subset = Sepal.Width) # works
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5           2          3.5           1 versicolor
```

However, using the curly brackets, `{{ subset}}` is evaluating too early when `subset = NULL` and is trying to filter where `NULL < 2.2`. `f()` returns the following error:

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
>
> x Input `..1` must be of size 150 or 1, not size 0.
>
> i Input `..1` is `NULL < 2.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should evaluate `is.null(substitute(subset))` in the function body, not within the `if` clause. That clause is evaluated differently (due to `%>%` stack management) than in the parent.

This works:

```r
f <- function(subset = NULL){
  isnull <- is.null(substitute(subset))
  iris %>% 
    {if (isnull) . else filter(., {{ subset }} < 2.2)}
}

head( f() )
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
f(subset = Sepal.Width)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1            5           2          3.5           1 versicolor
```

Comment: (I didn't see akrun's answer before posting this, not sure why, but this resolves your second-expression.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to return the full dataset when an `error` happens with `tryCatch`

```
f <- function(subset = NULL){

  tryCatch(  iris %>% 
    filter({{ subset }} < 2.2)
      , error = function(err) iris)
    

 }
```

-testing

```
dim(f())
#[1] 150   5

dim(f(subset = Sepal.Width))
#[1] 1 5
```

Comment: +1 for the use of python's "ask forgiveness" method, unfortunately R doesn't perform nearly as well with `tryCatch(., error=)` as python does with `try: . except:` (it's unfortunately significantly slower in R).

Answer (score 1):

I found an approach which is probably not the most elegant, but it has the advantage of being fairly legible and intuitive.

First I turn the object into a string and compare with the variables in the dataset. If the object you entered is not there, it will just return the data as is. If in turn the column is in the dataset, it will filter it using the bang-bang operator `!!` in combination with `sym` which converts your string to a symbol.

Hope that works for you.

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(data, subset = NULL, value = 2.2) {
  subsetName = deparse(substitute(subset))

  if (!subsetName %in% names(data)) {return(data)}

  return(data %>% filter(!!sym(subsetName) < value))
}
```